# OnChange fires the first file input event

Tags: angularjs

I got this custome directive:

```
angular.module('uvox-player').directive('customOnChange', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var onChangeHandler = scope.$eval(attrs.customOnChange);
            element.bind('change', onChangeHandler);
        }
    };
});
```

And a view with 2 different inputs:

```
<div ng-show="platform == 'darwin'">
    <input class="ng-hide" id="input-file-id" multiple type="file" custom-on-change="importPlaylist"/>
    <label for="input-file-id" class="md-button md-raised md-primary">Import PlayList</label>
</div>


<div>
    <input class="ng-hide" id="input-file-id" multiple type="file" custom-on-change="importCover"/>
    <label for="input-file-id" class="md-button md-raised md-primary">New Cover</label>
</div>
```

When I click on the second input the event fired is the one declared in the first input: importPlaylist.

How can I solve this issue?
Thanks!

Extra: The methods where the onChange points to:

```
angular.module('uvox-player').controller('PlaylistBaseController', function($scope, Api, $state, $q, $http, $mdToast, ngDialog, $mdDialog) {

$scope.importPlaylist = function(event) {
    var file = event.target.files[0];
    Api.postPlaylistItunes('itunes[file]', file).then(function(data) {
        $state.reload();
    }, function(error) {
    });

}
```

And the second input method:

```
angular.module('uvox-player').controller('PlaylistCoverController', function($scope, Api, $state, $q, $http, $mdToast, ngDialog, $stateParams) {

$scope.selectPlaylist($stateParams.id);
Api.getPlaylist($stateParams.id).then(function(data) {
    $scope.cover = data.cover;
}, function(error) {
});


$scope.importCover = function(event) {
    var file = event.target.files[0];
    Api.postPlaylistCover($scope.selectedPlaylist, 'cover[file]', file).then(function(data) {
        $state.reload();
    }, function(error) {
    });

}
```

});

Comment: For the debugging purposes, could you remove the first input and see if the behaviour persists?

Comment: Yes, Already tried it, it's working ok.

Comment: Have you since fixed the issu?

Comment: No, I mean, if I remove the first input, the second works. The problem remains when having mpre than one input with the same custom-on-change tag.

Comment: This is not obiously not a normal behaviour and from what you have posted here it should've happen. So it's somewhere else in your code, so please post more, as the both methods

Comment: Which methods? If I'm not wrong, I think there is no more relevant code involved...

Comment: importPlaylist and importCover

Comment: added on the top

Comment: They are not in the same controller!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the right controllers were defined on the routing, the fail persisted until I realized that the erratic behavior is a result of having the same id on both inputs, as result of a copy/paste ....
Changed the id, problem solved....

Answer (score 0):

If you don't declare the controller AngularJs will look in the main controller and in your case it could've find the method importCover in PlaylistBaseController.

```
<div ng-controller="PlaylistBaseController" ng-show="platform == 'darwin'">
    <input class="ng-hide" id="input-file-id" multiple type="file" custom-on-change="importPlaylist"/>
    <label for="input-file-id" class="md-button md-raised md-primary">Import PlayList</label>
</div>


<div ng-controller="PlaylistCoverController">
    <input class="ng-hide" id="input-file-id" multiple type="file" custom-on-change="importCover"/>
    <label for="input-file-id" class="md-button md-raised md-primary">New Cover</label>
</div>
```

Comment: makes perfect sense ;-) I'll check it this evening and confirm and vote. Thanks soooo much ;-)

Comment: Just checked now ... No luck :-( It still calling the first method

Comment: To resume, when you change the value on "new cover" importPlaylist is fired?

Comment: How do you know that ? have you put console.logs() in each of two? I may ask obvious things but just to be sure :)

Comment: That could be not very revealing. How about put console.log("1") and console.log("2") in each of functions and see which one is fired?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152186/discussion-between-arcovoltaico-and-vega).